# Spark sql converts bad records to Null while doing datatype casting

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

```scala
val simpleData = Seq(Row("James ","","Smith","36636","M",3000),
  Row("Michael ","Rose","","40288","M",4000),
  Row("Robert ","","Williams","42114","M",4000),
  Row("Maria ","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
  Row("Jen","Mary","Brown","bad","F",-1)
)
    
val simpleSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("firstname",StringType,true),
  StructField("middlename",StringType,true),
  StructField("lastname",StringType,true),
  StructField("id", StringType, true),
  StructField("gender", StringType, true),
  StructField("salary", IntegerType, true)
))
    
val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(simpleData),simpleSchema)

+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
|firstname|middlename|lastname|   id|gender|salary|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
|   James |          |   Smith|36636|     M|  3000|
| Michael |      Rose|        |40288|     M|  4000|
|  Robert |          |Williams|42114|     M|  4000|
|   Maria |      Anne|   Jones|39192|     F|  4000|
|      Jen|      Mary|   Brown|Rose |     F|    -1|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+------+------+
```

I am running sample code below where I want to convert a string column to an integer after casting.

```scala
df.createOrReplaceTempView("EMP")
val df2 = spark.sql("select cast(id as INT) from EMP")

+-----+
|   id|
+-----+
|36636|
|40288|
|42114|
|39192|
| null|
+-----+
```

Here all integer data converted correctly however "Rose" converted to null.

Could you please help me with how to throw an exception whenever there is a bad record?
Are there any spark config settings for this?

Also, how to get the exact column name that is having this issue if there are multiple casts in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Spark 3.0 and correction of ticket [SPARK-30292](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30292), setting `spark.sql.ansi.enabled` config to `true` will raise an exception when you try to cast invalid string to a number:

```scala
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.ansi.enabled", "true")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("EMP")
val df2 = spark.sql("select cast(id as INT) from EMP")
```

throws a `NumberFormatException`. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-ansi-compliance.html#cast for more details.

Comment: Thanks, @Vincent This solution has worked. If possible, could you please help me with the second question?  If there are multiple casts then it would be difficult to find the exact column name as in the error log, I don't see any column name from where the exception was generated.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately, I don't know how to answer the second part of your question. Maybe as suggested in [Robert Kossendey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70112066/6807769) by creating an UDF

Answer (score 2):

Spark does not throw if a cast goes wrong.

As a custom approach to catch those errors you could write a [UDF](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-udf-user-defined-function/) that throws if you cast to null. This worsens the performance of your script though, since Spark can not optimise UDF executions.